# PowerShell SQL scripting USPs and Users

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, database-administration

I have put together the below PowerShell script which scripts out all the USPs on a server.

Is there an option to split the output into individual files (instead of saving as one whole/large file)?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path SQLSERVER:\SQL\myserver\Default\Databases\mydb\StoredProcedures\ | %{$_.script() | out-file -Filepath "myfilelocation.sql"}
```

Comment: Have you tried placing your pipe into `Out-File` inside your `Foreach-Object` (%) scriptblock? i.e `%{ $_.Script() | Out-File ... }`

Comment: @Shaneis Thanks. Getting closer. I've added the Out-File into the pipe, and I can see it's doing everything individually (as the file grows, then reduces repeatedly) - but not sure how to introduce the Foreach-Object so that a separate file is produced for each. 

`Get-ChildItem -Path SQLSERVER:\SQL\my server\Default\Databases\mydb\StoredProcedures\ | %{$_.script() | out-file -Filepath "mylocation_$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).sql"}`

Comment: That's because you're over-writing your file each time. These scripts should finish fast so they're all going to finish within the same day (hopefully). Try adding the time or the name of the procedure you're scripting to make the file name unique and see if that helps you. Or else use `-Append` after the `.sql"` bit

Answer (score 0):

Try the following; it should append the procedure name to the file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path SQLSERVER:\SQL\myserver\Default\Databases\mydb\StoredProcedures\ | 
    %{    
          #Deal with invalid chars in Procedure name i.e. [Customers\Remove]
          $SProc = "$($_.name -replace '\\', '_')"

          # $Sproc | Out-Host # Uncomment this to check the procedure names...

          $_.script() | 
          out-file -Filepath "myfilelocation_$SProc.sql"
     }
```

This should make the file name unique per database and not have the file over-written each time. That is what is currently happening with your script.

Comment: I see your thinking, but doesn't quite get me there. Error message received - 

`out-file : Cannot perform operation because the wildcard path ........ did not resolve to a file`

Comment: I had that issue once or twice and the problem was that a developer had put a '\' in the name of one of the procedures. I'll edit the answer to reflect this but it may be another character.